# (Method used ?)Asymptotic of an integral equation

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I'm currently reading a paper where the authors present an integral equation, and its resulting asymptotic. I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of the method used. The integral equation is given by

\begin{align*}
u(x,k) =1 &+\int_{x}^\infty \frac{1}{3k^2}\left[1+\alpha e^{(\alpha -1)k(x-t)}+\alpha^2e^{(\alpha^2-1)k(x-t)}\right]\left[q^{\prime}(t)-ip(t)\right]u(t,k)\ dt\\
&-\int_{x}^\infty \frac{1}{3k}\left[1+\alpha^2e^{(\alpha-1)k(x-t)}+\alpha e^{(\alpha^2-1)k(x-t)}\right]2q(t)u(t,k)\ dt,
\end{align*}
where
$\alpha=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$, and $k\in \mathbb{C}$ (here $k$ has a further restriction, but I'm just looking for the general idea of the work done to find the below).
The resulting asymptotic as $k\to \infty$ is then given by
$u(x,k)=1-\frac{2}{3k}\int_x^\infty q(t)\ dt+\frac{1}{3k^2}\int_x^\infty \left[q^{\prime}(t)-ip(t)\right]\ dt +\frac{4}{9k^2}\int_x^\infty \ dt\ q(t)\int_t^\infty \ ds\ q(s)+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right).$

Any reference as to the technique/method used would be much appreciated. Thank you.